# I added user control to place holder . when fire button any user control to place holder not fire code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used User Control and Placeholder when added uc to place holder. Count place holder is 0. And then clicking the button on uc does not fire any code. All viewstate is ok, and I don't know what happened.

I used this class to add user control:

```
 public abstract class MasterControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1;

        public void Initial(bool postback =true)
        {

            this.CurrenetContorl = (BaseUserControl)this.LoadControl(this.CurrentPath);
            this.CurrenetContorl.PostBack = this.FristLoad ? !FristLoad : postback;
            this.CurrenetContorl.PreviousControl = this.PreviousControl;
            this.CurrenetContorl.CurrentControl = this.CurrentPath;
            if (!this.PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<BaseUserControl>().Any( x=> x.ID.Equals(this.CurrenetContorl.ID)))
            {
                this.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(this.CurrenetContorl);
                this.FristLoad = false;

            }
        }

        private BaseUserControl _currentcontrol;

        public BaseUserControl CurrenetContorl
        {
            get { return _currentcontrol; }
            set { 
                _currentcontrol = value;
                if (_currentcontrol == null) return;
                _currentcontrol.Redirecting += CurrentControlRedirecting;
                _currentcontrol.ID = this.GetId;

            }
        }
        private bool FristLoad = false;
        void CurrentControlRedirecting(string url)
        {
           var ctrl= this.PlaceHolder1.Controls.OfType<BaseUserControl>().FirstOrDefault();
           if (ctrl != null)
           {
               this.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
               this.PreviousControl = ctrl.GetType().Name;

           }
           this.CurrnetUrl = url;
           this.Initial(false);
        }

        public string CurrnetUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ViewState["currentUrl"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                var temp = "";
                if (value.StartsWith("/"))
                {
                    temp = "http://"+Request.Url.Authority +value;
                }
                this.ViewState["currentUrl"] = temp;
                this.CurrentPath = this.GetPath();
            }
        }

        private string GetPath()
        {
            var uri = new  Uri(this.CurrnetUrl);
            return uri.AbsolutePath;
        }
        public string PreviousControl
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ViewState["_previousControl"] == null)
                    this.ViewState["_previousControl"] = string.Empty;
                return this.ViewState["_previousControl"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                this.ViewState["_previousControl"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected string CurrentPath
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ViewState["_currentpath"] == null)

                    this.ViewState["_currentpath"] = string.Empty;

                return this.ViewState["_currentpath"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                this.ViewState["_currentpath"] = value;
            }
        }
        private string GetId
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ViewState["ControlId"] == null)
                    this.ViewState["ControlId"] = Guid.NewGuid();
                return this.ViewState["ControlId"].ToString();
            }
        }

        public void Redirect(string url)

        {
            this.CurrentControlRedirecting(url);
        }

        public void LoadUrl(string url)
        {
            this.CurrnetUrl = url;
            this.CurrenetContorl = (BaseUserControl)this.LoadControl(this.CurrentPath);
            this.FristLoad = true;
            this.PreviousControl = "";
        }
    }

    public abstract class BaseUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public string PreviousControl
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ViewState["precontrol"] == null)
                    this.ViewState["precontrol"] = string.Empty;
                return this.ViewState["precontrol"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                this.ViewState["precontrol"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string CurrentControl
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ViewState["ccontrol"] == null)
                    this.ViewState["ccontrol"] = string.Empty;
                return this.ViewState["ccontrol"].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                this.ViewState["ccontrol"] = value;
            }
        }
        public delegate void RedirectHandler(string url);
        public event RedirectHandler Redirecting;

        public bool PostBack
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ViewState["_postBack"] == null)
                    this.ViewState["_postBack"] = false;
                return this.ViewState["_postBack"].ToString().ToBol();
            }
            set
            {
                this.ViewState["_postBack"] = value;
            }
        }


        public void Redirect(string url)
        {
            this.Redirecting(url);
        }
    }
    public abstract class BaseUserControl<T> : BaseUserControl
    {
        public virtual void GetDataFromControl(T obj)
        {
            this.TryUpdateModel(obj);
        }
        public virtual void LoadControl(T obj)
        {
            this.TryBindModel(obj);
        }
    }
```

main.ascx code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Main : MasterControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {

            }






        }

        protected void RadMenu1_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.Item.Selected != null)
            {
                this.Redirect(e.Item.Value);
            }


        }
    }
}
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Main" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="RadMenu_WebBlue">
    <telerik:RadMenu ID="RadMenu1" runat="server" OnItemClick="RadMenu1_ItemClick" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False"  >
        <Items>

            <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="مطالب" >
               <Items>
                   <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="ایجاد مطلب جدید"  Value="/CreatePost.ascx" />
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="ارشیو مطالب"  Value="/ArchivePost.ascx"></telerik:RadMenuItem>
               </Items>
            </telerik:RadMenuItem>


             <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" Text="تغییر رمز عبور" Value="/changePassword.ascx"></telerik:RadMenuItem>



        </Items>
    </telerik:RadMenu>
    </div>
<asp:PlaceHolder EnableViewState="True" ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: You should cut on the code a bit, find the critical lines/blocks and explain more what your question is about, what the problem is and what you've tried

Comment: i add user control to main.ascx when get placeholder.controls.count is 0 . then cant run code behind any user control added in main.ascx

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize usercontrol in main page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        this.Initialize();

    }
```